# Lambdas and std::function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11

I'm trying to catch up on C++11 and all the great new features. I'm a bit stuck on lambdas.

Here's the code I was able to get to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<typename BaseT, typename Func>
vector<BaseT> findMatches(vector<BaseT> search, Func func)
{
    vector<BaseT> tmp;

    for(auto item : search)
    {
        if( func(item) )
        {
            tmp.push_back(item);
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}

void Lambdas()
{
    vector<int> testv = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    auto result = findMatches(testv, [] (const int &x) { return x % 2 == 0; });

    for(auto i : result)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Lambdas();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What I would like to have is this:

```
template<typename BaseT>
vector<BaseT> findMatches(vector<BaseT> search, function <bool (const BaseT &)> func)
{
    vector<BaseT> tmp;

    for(auto item : search)
    {
        if( func(item) )
        {
            tmp.push_back(item);
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Basically I want to narrow down the possible lambdas to a sensible subset of functions.
What am I missing? Is this even possible? I'm using GCC/G++ 4.6.

Comment: If you do what you want (i.e. using `std::function`) what errors do you get? Also not that some C++11 support is not fully supported in GCC, not even in GCC 4.7 much less in 4.6.

Comment: Your second code sample looks good; what error do you get?

Comment: Templates only allow exact matches, so you cannot pass a lambda to a function template expecting an `std::function`. Moreover, the `function` constructor is not required to reject arguments that do not actually match the `function` signature, so it is not actually useful to narrow things down.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but since you are learning C++11 features, you should look up [initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists). To create your test vector, you can simply do `vector<int> testv{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};` instead of using consecutive `push_back`s.

Comment: @JohannesD: Template functions definitely do allow inexact matches. E.g. `std::make_pair<int, long>(5L, 3.0)` will convert a long to an int, and a double to a long. The problem here is that Template Argument Deduction doesn't work. There's no way to deduce `BaseT`.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, I was being inexact. Template argument deduction was what I meant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stephan T. Lavavej explains why this doesn't work in [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-2-of-n). Basically, the problem is that the compiler tries to deduce `BaseT` from *both* the `std::vector` *and* the `std::function` parameter. A lambda in C++ is *not* of type `std::function`, it's an unnamed, unique non-union type that is convertible to a function pointer if it doesn't have a capture list (empty `[]`). On the other hand, a `std::function` object can be created from any possible type of callable entity (function pointers, member function pointers, function objects).

Note that I personally don't understand why you would want to limit the incoming functors to that specific signature (in addition to the fact that indirection through a polymorphic function wrapper, like `std::function`, is by far more inefficient than a direct call to a functor (which may even be inlined)), but here's a working version. Basically, it disables argument deduction on the `std::function` part, and only deduces `BaseT` from the `std::vector` argument:

```
template<class T>
struct Identity{
  typedef T type;
};

template<typename BaseT>
vector<BaseT> findMatches(vector<BaseT> search, 
    typename Identity<function<bool (const BaseT &)>>::type func)
{
    vector<BaseT> tmp;

    for(auto item : search)
    {
        if( func(item) )
        {
            tmp.push_back(item);
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/cDaLF)

Another possible way would be to not restrict the functor type directly, but indirectly through SFINAE:

```
template<class T, class F>
auto f(std::vector<T> v, F fun)
    -> decltype(bool(fun(v[0])), void())
{
  // ...
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/dhyxN)

This function will be removed from the overload set if `fun` doesn't take an argument of type `T&` or if the return type is not convertible to `bool`. The `, void()` makes `f`'s return type `void`.

Comment: So to clarify, the OP's code sample fails because the compiler is trying to do template argument deduction on the `std::function` argument?

Comment: No need for `Identity`: Just use `std::common_type<T>::type`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Meh, I think it's clearer for this answer, since the implementation of `Identity` is pretty transparent. Also clarified the lambda conversion part.

Comment: @Xeo : i wan't to prevent the passing in of some lamda which may not return a bool or passes a const ref to a string, when the vector is of type int. I basically wan't to use it like a delegate in C#, maybe that's my problem to begin with.

Comment: @Mithrandir: C++'s type system will handle that for you, it will simply fail to compile if `fun`'s return type isn't convertible to bool (which it needs to be to be used in an `if` statement) or if `fun` doesn't accept an argument of type `BaseT`. The second code, the SFINAE one, just gives a cleaner error message.

Comment: @Xeo You're quite right. Well my C++ days date from the late 90's and it seems i'll have  to relearn some basics. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Xeo it can be made even clearer with `template <typename T> using NotDeducible = typename identity<T>::type;`. :P

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Sure thing, but alas, not all compilers support using-aliases. :( This code should be portable with minimal C++11 compatability.

Answer (score 0):

As has been revealed by other posters, this is a template argument deduction for std::function.

One intuitive way to make the second code snippet work is to add your base type when calling the template function: `findMatches<int>`.

Another way not mentioned by Xeo is using std::is_convertible:

```
template<typename BaseT, typename FUNC>
vector<BaseT> findMatches(vector<BaseT> search, function <bool (const BaseT &)> func)
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<FUNC, function<bool (const BaseT &)> >::value, "func must be convertible to ...");

    vector<BaseT> tmp;

    for(auto item : search)
    {
        if( func(item) )
        {
            tmp.push_back(item);
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

It avoids wrapping lamda into std::function, and provides a cleaner error message.