# How is type deduced from auto return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype, return-type-deduction

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11774533/476681) has a code snippet like this :

```
template<class T, class F>
auto f(std::vector<T> v, F fun)
    -> decltype( bool( fun(v[0] ) ), void() )
{
  // ...
}
```

It really compiles and work ([at least on Ideone](http://ideone.com/dhyxN)).

So, how is the type deduced in this case?

Is next line really allowed by c++11 standard?

```
decltype( bool( fun(v[0] ) ), void() )
```

I took a quick look, and it doesn't look valid. Is ideone wrong in this case?

---

All examples in the c++11 standard are such that they all got only one type in the decltype :

```
struct A {
  char g();
  template<class T> auto f(T t) -> decltype(t + g())
  { return t + g(); }
};
```

another example :

```
void f3() {
  float x, &r = x;
  [=] {
  decltype(x) y1;
  decltype((x)) y2 = y1;
  decltype(r) r1 = y1;
  decltype((r)) r2 = y2;
};
```

and another

```
const int&& foo();
int i;
struct A { double x; };
const A* a = new A();
decltype(foo()) x1 = i;
decltype(i) x2;
decltype(a->x) x3;
decltype((a->x)) x4 = x3;
```

They all got only one parameter in decltype. How come the top code take two parameters (separated by a comma)?

---

I created another example (which fails to compile) :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class F>
auto f(std::vector<T> v, F fun) -> decltype(bool(fun(v[0])), void())
{
  // ...
  (void)v;(void)fun;

  return fun(v.size());
}

void ops(int)
{
}

int main(){
  std::vector<int> v;
  f(v, [](int){ return true; });
  f(v,ops);
}
```

Even if the line `f(v,ops);` is removed, the return type of the `f` template function is evaluated to void.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't look valid? I don't really know what to put in an answer that will help, besides "It is valid".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Hope it's more clear after the edit. The question is what happens here :`decltype( bool( fun(v[0] ) ), void() )`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`decltype( bool( fun(v[0] ) ), void() )` uses the [*comma operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator).

Breaking it down,

```
bool( fun(v[0] ) ), void()
```

is composed of two expressions; the first

```
bool( fun(v[0] ) )
```

is evaluated<sup>1</sup> and discarded, giving the overall expression the value

```
void()
```

which is a value<sup>2</sup> of type `void`.

`decltype` then yields the type of the expression, which as above is `void`.

The reason to use the comma operator here is to ensure that the whole expression is only valid if the first subexpression is valid; this is because it is being used in SFINAE to exclude it from substitution consideration if the first subexpression is invalid.

This works because although `decltype` looks syntactically like a function, it is actually a language construct that (like `sizeof`) is defined to take a single argument.  It might be clearer to parenthesise the comma-operator argument:

```
decltype( ( bool( fun(v[0] ) ), void() ) )
```

#### Notes

1. The expression `bool( fun(v[0] ) )` is not *actually* evaluated, because we're in a *non-evaluated context* (`decltype`, similar to `sizeof`). What matters here is that it *would be* evaluated if the expression as a whole was evaluated, so that if the subexpression is invalid then the whole expression is invalid.
2. `void()` isn't *really* a value, but it behaves like a value in the context of the comma operator and `decltype`.

Comment: Is the first operand of the comma really evaluated?

Comment: @Kerrek Well, in this case, nothing is evaluated.

Comment: @Kerrek: It would be, if the whole expression wasn't inside a non-evaluated context (`decltype` in this case). ;)

Comment: Does `void()` really mean `void`? In template declarations it's an anonymous pointer to a function returning void, isn't it?

Comment: @jrok: Where a type is required, (like `std::function<void()>`), it's a function type. In a function parameter, it's still a function type, but is transformed, per language requirement, to be equivalent to `void (*)()`, aka a function pointer type. Where an expression is required, it's a "value" of type `void`. Which can be abused, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11691101/500104). ;)

Comment: @Michael: Why wouldn't it? Evaluating means calling functions, operators, ctors, whatever else, and none of that is needed to have the typesystem shout at you because you provided non-matching types. Values are completely non-interesting here, only types matter, and for those, you don't need to evaluate anything.

Comment: So, the return type is always void?

Comment: @BЈовић: The return type of `f` will always be `void`, yes.

Comment: I call the "evaluations" that `decltype` and `sizeof` perform "e-type-uations" :)

Answer (score 7):

`decltype` yields the type of the expression between the parenthesis, **without actually evaluating it** (keep that in mind for the next parts).

The `,` operator evaluates the left argument / expression, throws the result away, evaluates the right argument, and yields that result. As such, the return type becomes `void`.

For the `bool(fun(v[0]))` part, it's rather easy. `bool(f(...))` constructs a bool temporary from the result of calling `f`. If the return type of `f` isn't convertible to `bool`, this will trigger an error, which will lead to SFINAE thanks to being inside `decltype` (this is called ["Expression SFINAE"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html)).

`f(v[0])` will pass the return value of `v[0]` to `f`, which is of type `T&`. If `f` doesn't have a parameter that `T&` is convertible to, or takes more / less parameters, this will trigger an error, and again, will lead to SFINAE for the same reason as above.

(The same would happen if `std::vector` wouldn't support `operator[]`.)