# lambda expression and template deduction against std::function: why this works?

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function, template-argument-deduction

My question is somewhat related to this question:
[Lambdas and std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774277/lambdas-and-stdfunction?no). Please read this question and its accepted answer.

So, the accepted answer says that the following code makes template parameter deducing against lambdas succeed, but why?

```
template<class T>
struct Identity{
  typedef T type;//why this helps?
};

template<typename BaseT>
vector<BaseT> findMatches(vector<BaseT> search, 
    typename Identity<function<bool (const BaseT &)>>::type func)
{
    vector<BaseT> tmp;

    for(auto item : search)
    {
        if( func(item) )
        {
            tmp.push_back(item);
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}

void Lambdas()
{
    vector<int> testv = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    auto result = findMatches(testv, [] (const int &x) { return x % 2 == 0; });//lambda here.

    for(auto i : result)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Lambdas();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The code above is working, but I don't know why. Firstly, I know the template deduction of `BaseT` does not happen for lambda because that's a non-deducible context(`Identify<function<bool (const BaseT &)>>::type`). Instead, `BaseT` is deduced from `testv` as `int`, and template parameter substitution happens in `Identity<function<bool (const BaseT &)>>::type`.

But what's next? after substitution, `Identity<function<bool (const BaseT &)>>::type` becomes `function<bool (const BaseT &)>`, but isn't lambda expression not of that type, and conversions does not happen in template parameter deduction(although here is template parameter substitution)?

Thanks for your explaining! 
P.S. I seem to know compiler generate unique-named class for each lambda expression. So why lambda can match with `function<bool (const BaseT &)>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what's next? after substitution, `Identity<function<bool (const BaseT &)>>::type` becomes `function<bool (const BaseT &)>`, but isn't lambda expression not of that type, and conversions does not happen in template parameter deduction(although here is template parameter substitution)?

You're correct that there is no subisitution during template argument deduction but once that has been completed we treat the function call as calling the instantiated function. 
 That means `Identity<function<bool (const BaseT &)>>::type` has been substituted with `function<bool (const BaseT &)>` your instantiated function you are calling is:

```
vector<int> findMatches(vector<int> search, function<bool (const int&)> func)
```

Since it is taking a concrete `function<bool (const int&)>` the lambda can be using to construct `func`

Comment: So it is working because after the function template being instantiated, lambda expression is implicitly converted to lambda during the function overload phase (stage)? So the procedure is template parameter deduction -> template parameter substitution -> overload resolution (where conversions happen?)

Comment: @HanXIAO Basically.  Remember that a function template is not a function, it is a recipe on how to make one.  So once you deduce the template parameters then you stamp out a function that uses the actual deduced types.  It is this function that you actually call and since it has a real type of `functional<bool (const int&)>` the lambda can be converted.

Answer (score 1):

This works because the type for the `func` parameter is *not* deduced.
By using the external trait class `Idendity`, the code makes the type for the `func` parameter dependent on the `BaseT` template parameter, turning it into a non-deduced context.

Therefore, what happens is that `BaseT` gets deduced for the `search` parameter and de-facto the type for `func`, being dependent on `BaseT`, becomes known. In the end, your lambda can be implicitly converted to the desired `std::function<bool(int const&)>` type.

If you omit this trick to make `func`'s type dependent on `BaseT`, eg.:

```
template<typename BaseT>
vector<BaseT> findMatches(vector<BaseT> search, 
     function<bool (const BaseT &)> func)
```

Then, template argument deduction also takes place for `func` and would yield a compiler error.